# Installing .net Framework 1.1 globally configured all my websites for 1.1 How do I undo this/permanently reconfigure them back to asp.net 2.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, iis-7, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-1.1, aspnet-regiis.exe

I have a Windows 7 machine on which I am using VS2005. .Net 2.0 and .Net 3.5 are installed on it.

An app claimed it needed .NET framework 1.1 before it would run.
I therefore installed framework 1.1 and it now runs.

Problem:
Now whenever I try to open a website in VS2005  I get a messages saying it is configured for 1.1 rather than 2.0. VS2005 offers to configure the website - but whatever changes it makes are non-permanent and when next I open the website I get the same message.

I have tried removing and re-adding a website: still configured for 1.1.

I appear to have a new AppPool named "ASP.NET 1.1" - but no applications are associated with that.

Is there a way to un-do the global change installing 1.1 made to my websites?

When 1.1 installed I saw "aspnet_regiis /i" being invoked as part of the install:
I have tried running the Framework 2.0 version of "aspnet_regiis /i" on the off chance - no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure you don't need .NET 1.1 for any of the web applications, you can run `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -u -e` to remove the v1.1 hooks. Then you can run `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i -r -enable` to re-enable all the v2.0 hooks. (Or you may be able to just set ASP.NET 1.1 to "Prohibit" under the Web Service Extensions section of the IIS control panel.)

Otherwise, you will need to use the IIS control panel to manually set the ASP.NET version back to 2.0 on each of the virtual directories which need it. The ones with the orangish gears are the ones using dynamic content, so if you right-click them and go to the ASP.NET tab, you'll see where you can change the version back to v2.0.

Comment: Using "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -e" then "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -u" seems to have done the trick. Cheers.